# Target text overlaying an image

Tags: jquery, css, hover, styles, overlay

I am trying for hours to get this hover image to have the text that comes on top of it to show white instead of black and I can't figure this out.

I have tried several blending modes and the best I did was to get all of the text to show white, but I only want to target the text over the image.

The page I am working on is this: https://staging.gilreyesdesign.com/

Thank you so much!

This is the style I am working with:

```
<style>
/* .txt-box:hover p:not(a) {
    color: white;;
} */

.container-items {
    position:relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer; }

.container-img-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: -43rem;
    left: -25rem;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    visibility: hidden; }

.container-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;}

</style>
```

This is the script I am using:

```
    <script>
const allcontainer = gsap.utils.toArray(".container-item");
const venueImageWrap = document.querySelector(".container-img-wrap");
const venueImage = document.querySelector(".container-img");

function initcontainer() {
            allcontainer.forEach((link) => {
                link.addEventListener("mouseenter", venueHover);
                link.addEventListener("mouseleave", venueHover);
                link.addEventListener("mousemove", moveVenueImage);
            });
        }
        
function moveVenueImage(e) {
            let xpos = e.clientX;
            let ypos = e.clientY;
            const tl = gsap.timeline();
            tl.to(venueImageWrap, {
                x: xpos,
                y: ypos,
            });
        }

function venueHover(e) {
            if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
                const targetImage = e.target.dataset.img;
                
const tl = gsap.timeline();
                tl.set(venueImage, {
                    backgroundImage: `url(${targetImage})`,
                }).to(venueImageWrap, {
                    duration: 0.5,
                    autoAlpha: 1,
                });
            } else if (e.type === "mouseleave") {
                const tl = gsap.timeline();
                tl.to(venueImageWrap, {
                    duration: 0.5,
                    autoAlpha: 0,
                });
            }
        }

function init() {
            initcontainer();
        }

        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            init();
        });

        tl = new TimelineMax();

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

z-index should do the trick, and you are on the right track to create contrast. Check my reply comments.

```
container-img-wrap {
  z-index: 9999;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

Or maybe you need to add some contrast by adding a border to the text.

```
.container-img-wrap {
    /*z-index: 9999;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    filter: invert(1);*/
}

.elementor-widget-text-editor {
    text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #fff, -2px 0 0 #fff, 0 2px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 0 #fff, 1px 1px #fff, -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff;;
}
```

Comment: I was able to add it and it does work on getting the image to overlay the text, but I can't get the text to be white underneath. I tried a blend mode and it works for a bit, but when I stop the mouse, the bend mode modifies the image and stops modifying the text.

You can see it here: 
https://staging.gilreyesdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Screen-Shot-2021-03-10-at-7.33.40-PM.png

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this with CSS. You want to affect the font color of the other element (the text) based on the position of the photo. Furthermore, you not only want individual letters of the text to change, but parts of each letters to change. Maybe using canvas and/or SVGs, but that algorithm will be complex. How about adding a white border to the text instead?